# %al register in C code

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly

```
testb  $1, %al
je     .L3
leal   1(%eax,%eax,2), %eax
jmp    .L4
```

I am given the above assembly code and asked to translate it to c code.

I know what almost all of it is doing, I just don't know how to to do C code for the `%al` register.

Here Is the rest of the assembly code if it helps

```
prob2:
pushl  %ebp
movl   %esp, %ebp
movl   8(%ebp), %eax
cmpl   $1, %eax
je     .L1
.L6:
testb  $1, %al
je     .L3
leal   1(%eax,%eax,2), %eax
jmp    .L4
.L3:
shrl   %eax
.L4:
cmpl   $1, %eax
jne    .L6
.L1:
popl   %ebp
ret
```

Comment: `al` is the low 8 bits of `eax`; usually, it is used to represent a `char` in C. (Here, that's not the case, though).

Comment: It just checks if the least significant bit of a value is set, i.e. if the value is odd.

Comment: Include the C code you already have figured into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter here. Bit0 in `AL` is the same as Bit0 in `EAX`. The 8-bit operation was surely an optimization of the compiler. So you can read `AL` as `EAX`.