# Assembly code of a loop?

Tags: assembly

I'm having some issues understanding some of the parts of the assembly code I am suppose to decipher into a loop

```
prob2:
pushl  %ebp
movl   %esp, %ebp
movl   8(%ebp), %eax
cmpl   $1, %eax
je     .L1
.L6:
testb  $1, %al
je     .L3
leal   1(%eax,%eax,2), %eax
jmp    .L4
.L3:
shrl   %eax
.L4:
cmpl   $1, %eax
jne    .L6
.L1:
popl   %ebp
ret
```

Now I am given the general outline of the C code

```
void prob2(unsigned n)
{
while (________________) {
if (_______________) {
      ______________;
} else {
 _______________;
}
}
}
```

I've figured out that the while loop tests to see whether n < 1, but in the next if-else part I am confused as to what the %al part is. I assume it's testing to see if it is equal to 1 and if it is (which it never will be because the while loop breaks when n = 1) then it shifts n to the right by a byte else it does the leal part and compares to see if it's not equal to 1 yet.

Does that sound right?

Comment: There's a pretty common set of notation that works like this. **EAX** is the 32-bit A register. **RAX** is 64-bit. Just **AX** is 16-bit, which breaks into 8-bit **AH** (a high) and **AL** (a low). All these examples use the 'A' register but it extends to other registers the same way (EBX, RBX, BH, etc)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist So then it's doing something with the lower bits of the unsigned n that's passed in?

Comment: I haven't done assembly since college and I learned on [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) which looks a bit different, so take this with an appropriate grain of salt, but it looks to me like `testb` is the 1-byte (8-bit) version of the `test` command, and it's being used on just the last 8 bits of `EAX`.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33505506/3512216).

Answer (score 1):

`%al` is `l`owest byte of the register `%eax`, which is where you have determined that `n` is being kept (based on your interpretation of `cmpl $1, %eax`).

Comment: Okay, so then how would you access the %al part of n using C code? I think I have it. The while part tests if n is greater than 1, and if it is then we do some if statement with the lowest bits and if true then we shift right by a bit or we do leal 1(%eax,%eax,2)  which is... something

Comment: Look up the term *bit mask*: the idea is to zero-out the bits you aren't interested in, so you can test the whole register (or, in your case, variable).